# Cannot implicitly convert type IResponse to TResponse where TResponse : IResponse

Tags: c#

I have class `Test` that inherits `ITest<TRequest>`:

```
public interface ITest<TRequest>
{
    TResponse TestMethod <TResponse>(TRequest request) where TResponse : IResponse;
}
```

```
public class Test : ITest<Request>
{
    public TResponse TestMethod <TResponse>(Request request) where TResponse : IResponse
    {
        //Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'IResponse' to 'TResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        return this.TestMethod(request);
    }

    public IResponse TestMethod (Request request)
    {     
        IResponse response = new Response();     
        return response; 
    }
}
```

My question is why do I need to make an explicit conversion here?

Comment: Can you please code that can be compiled (except for the problem)?

Comment: ...using keywords such as `class` and `interface`

Comment: Works if you use correct types https://dotnetfiddle.net/GbZyX2

Comment: Hi @Charlieface this is the representation of my case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9KakHM

Comment: But `Response` isn't a `TResponse` so why would you expect this to work? All you know about `TResponse` is that it's an `IResponse`, it may be `Response` or may be a different class which supports `IResponse`.

Comment: I see, that was my confusion, now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`TestMethod<TResponse>` is a generic method, so it can be called with any type conforming to the requirement that it implements `IResponse`. For example:

```
internal class Response : IResponse{}
internal class AnotherResponse : IResponse{}
```

So what should happen when the next call happens:

```
new Test().TestMethod<AnotherResponse>();
```

Depending on what you need you can either change the method to be a non-generic one:

```
interface ITest<TRequest>
{
    IResponse TestMethod(TRequest request);
}
```

Or add second generic parameter to it:

```
interface ITest<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TResponse : IResponse
{
    TResponse TestMethod(TRequest request);
}

class Test : ITest<Request, Response>
{
    public Response TestMethod(Request request) => new Response();
}
```